# Nested capture_haml helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, helper

I have the following two helper methods:

```
def hello
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :div, 'Hello'
  end
end

def hello_world
  capture_haml do
    hello # How can I call it here?
    haml_tag :div, 'World'
  end
end
```

I want to call `hello` in `hello_world`. I tried `hello` alone, `capture_haml hello` and `haml_tag hello`, combined with `.html_safe` also but no solution would ever work.

How can I do that?

I'd really rather use `capture_haml` than `haml_tag` straight because I think having in the view

```
= hello_world
```

is much cleaner than

```
- hello_world
```

Thanks

Comment: You’re missing a `'` after `World` — is that just a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is just a typo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hello` method, since it is using `capture_haml` simply returns a string. When you call it inside the `capture_haml` block in the `hello_world` method it doesn’t do anything — a string is created and returned but you don’t use it at all. Since it isn’t written to the output it isn’t captured by the `capture_haml`.

You can write the string to the output, which will force `capture_haml` to work, with [`haml_concat`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_concat-instance_method), which would look like this:

```
def hello_world
  capture_haml do
    haml_concat hello
    haml_tag :div, 'World'
  end
end
```

This is a pretty contrived example, but I hope it shows what’s happening. `capture_haml` takes a block that would normally be written directly to the output (usually Haml source) and returns it as a string instead. `haml_concat` takes a string and writes it to the output, so is in some ways the opposite of `capture_haml`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. That's exactly what I was confused about!

Comment: Your mention of `haml_concat` just saved me from another hour of confusion, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
def hello
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :div, 'Hello'
  end
end

def hello_world
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :div, hello
    haml_tag :div, 'World'
  end
end
```